# PacemakerDRBD Mount Issue

Tags: lvm, drbd, pacemaker

We are stuck trying to get pacemaker to work with DRBD, and having tried various alternatives can't get our "drbd1" to mount and get some errors.

NOTE:  we are trying to get pacemaker to work with an existing Encrypted RAID1 LVM setup - is this impossible or a "just plain bad idea"?   We were thinking we'd like the potential advantages of local RAID on each box as well as the Internet RAID & failover provided by DRBD/pacemaker.  We're using Debian Squeeze.  Per various instructions, we've disabled the DRBD boot init (`update-rc.d -f drbd remove`) and set the LVM filter to `filter = [ "a|drbd.*|", "r|.*|" ]`.

FYI - we've commented out the LVM mount "/dev/vg2/vserverLV" in our fstab, and consistently seem to need to do this to avoid a boot error.

We think DRBD works until we add in the pacemaker steps (i.e., "dev/drbd1" mounts at boot; we can move related data from server1 to server2 back and forth, though need to use the command line to accomplish this).  We've seen various statements on the net that suggest it is viable to use a "mapper" choice in drbd.conf.  Also, if we start by configuring Pacemaker for a simple IP failover, that works (i.e., no errors, we can ping via the fail over address) but stops working when we add in the DRBD primatives and related statements.  Our suspicion (other than maybe "you can't do this with existing RAID") is that we're using the wrong "disk" statement in our drbd.conf, though we've tried lots of alternatives and this is the same drbd.conf we use before adding in Pacemaker and it seems to work at that point.

Lastly, while various config statements refer to "vservers", we have not gotten to the point of trying to add any data to the DRBD devices other than a few text files that have disappeared since doing our "crm" work.

Any help appreciated!

CONFIGS/LOGS

A) drbd.conf

```
global { usage-count no; }
common { syncer { rate 100M; } }
resource r1 {
    protocol C;
startup {
            wfc-timeout  15;
            degr-wfc-timeout 60;
    }
    device /dev/drbd1 minor 1;
      disk /dev/vg2/vserverLV;
    meta-disk internal;


    on server1 {
            address 192.168.1.129:7801;
             disk /dev/vg2/vserverLV;
    }
    on server2 {
            address 192.168.1.128:7801;
             disk /dev/vg2/vserverLV;
    }

     net {
    cram-hmac-alg sha1;
            shared-secret "secret";
              after-sb-0pri discard-younger-primary; #discard-zero-changes;
              after-sb-1pri discard-secondary;
              after-sb-2pri call-pri-lost-after-sb;
    }
}
```

B) Pacemaker Config

```
crm configure show

node server1
node server2
primitive app_ip ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr \
params ip="192.168.1.152" \
op monitor interval="30s"
primitive drbd ocf:linbit:drbd \
params drbd_resource="r1" \
op start interval="0" timeout="240" \
op stop interval="0" timeout="100" \
op monitor interval="59s" role="Master" timeout="30s" \
op monitor interval="60s" role="Slave" timeout="30s"
primitive fs_vservers ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem \
params device="/dev/drbd1" directory="/vservers" fstype="ext4" \
op start interval="0" timeout="60" \
op stop interval="0" timeout="120"
primitive vg2 ocf:heartbeat:LVM \
params volgrpname="vg2" exclusive="true" \
op start interval="0" timeout="30" \
op stop interval="0" timeout="30"
group lvm app_ip vg2 fs_vservers
ms ms_drbd drbd \
meta master-node-max="1" clone-max="2" clone-node-max="1" globally-unique="false"     notify="true" target-role="Master"
location drbd_on_node1 ms_drbd \
rule $id="drbd_on_node1-rule" $role="master" 100: #uname eq server1
colocation vserver-deps inf: ms_drbd:Master lvm
order app_on_drbd inf: ms_drbd:promote lvm:start
property $id="cib-bootstrap-options" \
dc-version="1.0.9-74392a28b7f31d7ddc86689598bd23114f58978b" \
cluster-infrastructure="openais" \
expected-quorum-votes="2" \
stonith-enabled="false" \
no-quorum-policy="ignore"
```

C)  crm results (with errors)

```
Last updated: Wed Feb 27 19:05:57 2013
Stack: openais
Current DC: server1 - partition with quorum
Version: 1.0.9-74392a28b7f31d7ddc86689598bd23114f58978b
2 Nodes configured, 2 expected votes
2 Resources configured.
============

Online: [ server2 server1 ]


Migration summary:
* Node server2: 
   drbd:1: migration-threshold=1000000 fail-count=1000000
* Node server1: 
   drbd:0: migration-threshold=1000000 fail-count=1000000

Failed actions:
    drbd:1_start_0 (node=server2, call=8, rc=-2, status=Timed Out): unknown exec error
    drbd:0_start_0 (node=server1, call=6, rc=-2, status=Timed Out): unknown exec error
```

D)  Mount (no "dev/drbd1").

```
/dev/mapper/vg1-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
tmpfs on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type tmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=620)
/dev/md0 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
/dev/mapper/vg1-home on /home type ext4 (rw)
/dev/mapper/vg1-tmp on /tmp type ext4 (rw)
/dev/mapper/vg1-usr on /usr type ext4 (rw)
/dev/mapper/vg1-var on /var type ext4 (rw)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
```

E)  fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
/dev/mapper/vg1-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/md0 during installation
UUID=25829c6c-164c-4a1e-9e84-6bab180e38f4 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/vg1-home /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/vg1-tmp /tmp            ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/vg1-usr /usr            ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/vg1-var /var            ext4    defaults        0       2
#/dev/mapper/vg2-vserverLV /vservers       ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/vg1-swap none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/scd0       /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
/dev/scd1       /media/cdrom1   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto  0       0
```

F)  fdisk -l

FYI In our Encrypted, RAID, LVM, md0 is RAID boot, md1 is encrypted and includes the OS in "vg1" with logical volumes for /, home, swap, use, var, and tmp.  md1 is encrypted and includes "vg2" and we start of with one logical volume "vserversLV" and mount point "vservers".

```
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0007c7a2

 Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          61      487424   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              61        1885    14648320   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3            1885        3101     9765888   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 203.9 GB, 203928109056 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 24792 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0008843c

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1          61      487424   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdb2              61        1885    14648320   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3            1885        3101     9765888   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md0: 499 MB, 499109888 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 121853 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md1: 15.0 GB, 14998757376 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 3661806 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x08040000

Disk /dev/md2: 9999 MB, 9999147008 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 2441198 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x08040000


Disk /dev/dm-0: 15.0 GB, 14997704704 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1823 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/dm-1: 3997 MB, 3997171712 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 485 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/dm-2: 1996 MB, 1996488704 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 242 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/dm-3: 1996 MB, 1996488704 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 242 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/dm-4: 3997 MB, 3997171712 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 485 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/dm-5: 1996 MB, 1996488704 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 242 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/dm-6: 499 MB, 499122176 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/dm-7: 9998 MB, 9998094336 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1215 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

G)  syslog excerpt

```
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr) Command '
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr) drbdsetup
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr)  
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr) 1
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr)  
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr) disk
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr)  
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr) /dev/vg2/vserverLV
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr)  
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr) /dev/vg2/vserverLV
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr)  
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr) internal
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr)  
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr) --set-defaults
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr)  
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr) --create-device
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr) ' terminated with exit code 20
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr) drbdadm attach r1: exited with code 20
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 drbd[2329]: ERROR: r1: Called drbdadm -c /etc/drbd.conf --peer server2 up r1
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 drbd[2329]: ERROR: r1: Exit code 1
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 drbd[2329]: ERROR: r1: Command output: 
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stdout) 
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr) Can not open device '/dev/vg2/vserverLV': No such file or directory
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr) Command 'drbdsetup 1 disk /dev/vg2/vserverLV 
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr) /dev/vg2/vserverLV internal --set-defaults --create-device' terminated with exit code 20#012drbdadm attach r1: exited with code 20
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 drbd[2329]: ERROR: r1: Called drbdadm -c /etc/drbd.conf --peer server2 up r1
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 drbd[2329]: ERROR: r1: Exit code 1
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 drbd[2329]: ERROR: r1: Command output: 
Feb 27 06:36:22 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stdout) 
Feb 27 06:36:23 server1 lrmd: [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr) Can not open device '/dev/vg2/vserverLV': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you may be following a guide or instructions on how to use DRBD as a physical disk for LVM. However, what you are trying to do is use LVM as the backing disk for DRBD. For this no extra configuration or special LVM filters is needed. Just simply specify the logical volume in the drbd config as the backing disk.
see: http://www.drbd.org/users-guide/s-lvm-lv-as-drbd-backing-dev.html

> RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stdout) Feb 27 06:36:23 server1 lrmd:
>   [1705]: info: RA output: (p_drbd_r1:0:start:stderr) Can not open
>   device '/dev/vg2/vserverLV': No such file or directory

The above error in the log shows that DRBD cannot find and attach to its backing disk. This is most likely due to your LVM filters preventing this volume group from being activated at boot.

Return your LVM filters to default, and remove the the`'primitive vg2 ocf:heartbeat:LVM` (and the order and colocation constraints that reference it) as vg2 needs to be activated before DRBD starts. Not by the cluster and not after DRBD.

As for using an encrypted volume as DRBD's backing disk it's really a non issue as long as it is unlocked and active before DRBD tries to attach to it. Which means either prompting for the key/passphrase at boot, or using something like crypttab to do this automatically. It is important to note that this encryption occurs underneath DRBD, and thus the replication traffic is still sent plaintext. So you may want to use a vpn for the replication traffic if this needs to be encrypted as well.

---

You can see in the logs that it's attempting to mount the filesystem before it has a chance to promote the DRBD resource. This fails as you cannot access the DRBD device unless it is primary.

Some ordering and colocation constraints should fix you up.

```
crm(live)configure# colocation fs_with_drbd_master inf: fs_vservers ms_drbd:Master
crm(live)configure# order fs_after_drbd inf: ms_drbd:promote fs_vservers:start
```

Also as DRBD is under pacemaker's control you do not want it starting at boot. Pacemaker will handle the starting at stopping. So, `"update-rc.d -f drbd remove"` is what you will want. Same goes for the filesystem. As the fileystem is now controlled by pacemaker do not include it in your fstab.

Comment: Thanks! We employed your crm config suggestions, and have gotten things to work. FYI - are not sure about this, but seemed part of the issue was our drbd.conf. When we used "mapper" in our statements (e.g., "dev/mapper/volumegroup-logicalvolume" vs."/dev/volumegroup/logicalvolume."). Could get DRBD to work with either, but pacemaker seemed to require that latter (without mapper)....maybe there was some way around this, but we could get the latter to work and not the former. Also, had to modify fstab to take out the related mount statement but our understanding is this may not be necessary with